# A problem with new "count(where:)" syntax in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

The problem is it doesn't compile.
Looks like there is no such a syntax.
But [the corresponding proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md) is marked as accepted.
And they use the syntax in several trusted articles: for example [here](https://www.swiftindepth.com/2019-01-27/stop-filtering) and in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syPKtPb0y-Y).
The exact code from video above doesn't compile:

```
import Foundation

let scores = [100, 80, 85]
let passCount = scores.count { $0 >= 85 }
```

Error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'

Comment: The proposal has been *accepted* but not yet  been *implemented.*

Comment: In fact it had to be *reverted:* https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/22289.

Comment: Do you see such a method in the docs? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SE-0220](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md) has been accepted, but not yet implemented in Swift 5.

In fact an initial implementation had to be [reverted](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/22289) due to problems with the type checker. For more information, see [Require parameter names when referencing to functions](https://forums.swift.org/t/require-parameter-names-when-referencing-to-functions/27048) in the Swift forum:

> Some of you may remember [SE-0220](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md), my proposal that added the
> count(where:) function to sequences. This proposal was ultimately
> accepted in time for Swift 5, but sadly had to be [reverted](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/22289) because
> it was causing issues with the type checker.
>
> The issue was that when you reference count, in an expression like
> `myArray.count * 5`, you could be referring to the `count` property, with
> type `Int`, or the `count(where:)` function, which has type
> `((Element) -> Bool) -> Int`, which you can refer to in shorthand as count. When Swift
> tries to resolve what version of the `*` function to use, it has to run
> through a lot more potential implementations, which explode
> combinatorially as you increase the number of operators in the
> expression.